# Print/list/check address blocks, matching a CIDR network prefix, from command line?

Tags: linux, networking, command-line, ip-address

I am not much of a network person, but I understand that (IPv4) addresses can be written in a format like `127.0.0.1/16`. I tried reading through Wikipedia's [IPv4 subnetting reference](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv4_subnetting_reference), [Subnetwork](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subnetwork) and [CIDR_notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CIDR_notation) - but it's way too much detail than I need.

I, essentially, don't need to understand CIDR notation for now - all I want is a command line tool, where I can type something like `127.0.0.1/16`, and see what addresses it matches.

Is there a command line tool I can use for the purpose?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try out `ipcal` available on, and from this webpage: http://www.jodies.de/ipcalc

Comment: Many thanks for that, @Squeezy - `ipcalc` looks like a fine Perl script, latest version currently seems to be [ipcalc-0.41](http://jodies.de/ipcalc-archive/ipcalc-0.41/); cheers!

Comment: Mate, where have you been the last 10 months? :D

Answer (score 0):

Well, searching through the Net, I accidentally found this:

- http://brandon.sternefamily.net/files/cidr.txt

It is a Python script, so I simply renamed it when I downloaded it, and used it like so:

```
$ wget http://brandon.sternefamily.net/files/cidr.txt -O cidr.py
$ python cidr.py 127.0.0.1/30
127.0.0.0
127.0.0.1
127.0.0.2
127.0.0.3
```

Would love to hear if there's anything else in existence that works like this...

Well, hope this helps someone,
Cheers!

---

EDIT: original link seems to be gone, here is archive: http://web.archive.org/web/20100307140430/http://brandon.sternefamily.net/files/cidr.txt

Answer (score 0):

you need prips:

```
$ prips 127.0.0.0/16
```

be careful it's going to print 65536 lines:

```
$ prips 127.0.0.0/16 | wc -l
65536
```

BTW: 127.0.0.1 is an incorrect input, as it is a *host* in a range, but you must specify a *network*. Use ipcalc to get a network:

```
$ ipcalc -b 127.0.0.1/16
```

Address:   127.0.0.1
Netmask:   255.255.0.0 = 16
Wildcard:  0.0.255.255
=>
**Network:   127.0.0.0/16**
HostMin:   127.0.0.1
HostMax:   127.0.255.254
Broadcast: 127.0.255.255
Hosts/Net: 65534                 Class A, Loopback